# WP: overriding recent post widget class

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, wordpress-hook

I want to customise the "recent posts" widget.
Since it's not good to edit the core for different reasons, I read about working it in functions.php extending `WP_Widget` with a new class and overriding the `widget($args, $instance)` function editing the code I want to customise, next to add it to the widget_init hook but I can't get how it works.
I mean, I think I should extend the `WP_Widget_Recent_Posts` then tell WP to use my class instead of the original one but....how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get away just by using the [dynamic_sidebar_params()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dynamic_sidebar_params/) filter along with a search/replace.

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'replace_widget_class' );

function replace_widget_class( $params ) {
    if ( $params[0]['widget_name'] == 'Recent Posts' ) {
        $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace( 'widget_recent_entries', 'widget_recent_entries_NEW', $params[0]['before_widget'] );
    }
    return $params;
}
```